# Java web project + JPA/JDBC "Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused"

Tags: java, database, jpa, persistence

I have this old web project which is called "Drinks Archive". You can, among other things, add, remove, list and edit drinks. It runs fine locally from NetBeans but when I deploy my project as a .war file to a server, which uses Tomcat 6, it gives the following error every time I try to do a database operation (e.g. add drink to db):

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.
>   Error Code: 40000
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:501)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:290)
>       org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:268)
>       archive.Register.getEntityManager(Register.java:53)
>       archive.Register.getDrinks(Register.java:170)
>       servlets.ListServlet.doGet(ListServlet.java:67)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Here's my source code, (in NetBeans I use GlassFish as a server).

Register.java:

```
public class Register {

private static Register instance;
private EntityManager em;

private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public static Register getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Rekisteri();
    }

    return instance;
}

private Register() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Rekisteri.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DrinksArchivePU");
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

public void addDrink(Drink new) {
    em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(new);
    em.getTransaction().commit();     
}

etc...//
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="DrinksArchivePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="d"/> 
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="d"/> 
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/drinks;create=true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I read that the problem could be because of derby network server not starting on my server but if that's so, how to fix it?

**EDIT:** Fixed, I changed to HSQLDB JDBC Driver in my persistence.xml settings and after that it was all about adding different missing jar-files to my project in the server.

Here's persistence.xml now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="DrinksAchivePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>archive.Ingredient</class>
    <class>archive.Review</class>
    <class>archive.Drink</class>
    <class>archive.DrinkCategory</class>
    <class>archive.User</class>
    <class>archive.Register</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;default_schema=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Is the database running on localhost on that server?

Comment: I'm not sure so probably not. What can I do about it?

Comment: Contact the system administrator and have them start it. Or start it yourself if there is no system administrator.

Comment: Have a look http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadi.html

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish comes with Java DB bundled. That's why it works on your local machine. Your deployment server either has a different database server configuration (check your persistence.xml) or no database server running at that port.